# sharing sqlite database between two android applications

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

i know that using content providers we can share database between two different applications. I have gone through so much tutorials for making custom content providers but not getting cleared. All i have it two editview and the values written should be saved in database and i want a second application to display this data in listview.. I have spent so many days reading contentproviders but not able to do. Please help. Thanks

Comment: did you consider to use a service for the communication between your apps? something like app1(with the sqlite database) provides a service to write data into sqlite. app2 binds the service and calls the method to write the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between two applications..Then You have no choice other than Content Providers.In your case it seems you can give a try to saving data into file.Your second application will read the file and fetch data.

Hope this help.

Comment: I am able to save data of app1 in sqlite,now i want to retrieve that data in app2 nd display it in listview